# Ruby/Mongo bulk update dyamic value from *found* document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, sinatra

I'm using the Ruby MongoDB Driver to interact with a Mongo database from a Sinatra app. I'm in the process of performing some bulk update operations and I have the need to update a document field's value based on the current value of the field in the found document.

I would like to do something like this:

```
my_bulk_op.find({
    'foo' => 'bar'
}).update({
    '$set' => {
        'my_field' => my_field += 1 # how can I get my_field's current value here?
    }
})
```

Is such an approach possible? I realize I can pre-find all the values and then perform the update, but in a lot of ways that defeats the purpose of the bulk operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following which has worked for me in the past with bulk operations:

```
my_bulk_op.find({
  'foo' => 'bar'
}).update({
  '$inc' => {
    'my_field' => 1
  }
})
```

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Comment: That's really useful, hopefully will help someone else with the same issue in the future as I am far removed from the project I posted about last year.